# document.getElementById wont give me "style" to change background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a function that "rolls" a dice, and I'm using netbeans to code my program, so when I write "document.getElementById." i dont get the "style" option, rather the only "s" is "seal".... I tried ignoring that and writing it either way, still didn't work, here's my code:

```
    <script>
        function roll()
        {
            var firstDie = document.getElementById("dice1");
            var secondDie = document.getElementById("dice2");

            firstDie.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
            secondDie.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);

            if (firstDie>secondDie)
            {
                document.getElementById("dice1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="game">
        <div id="dice1" class="dice">0</div>
        <div id="dice2" class="dice">0</div>

        <div id="feed" class="feed">
        <br><br>
        <button onclick="roll()" id="rollButton" class="rollButton">Roll</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you `console.log(document.getElementById("dice1").style)` do you get an object?

Comment: The problem is your `if` statement. You are compairing two `objects`, not two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just not entering the `if` statement because `domElement > otherElement` would be `false`.

`document.createElement('div') > document.createElement('div') //false`

What you want is:

```
var firstDieValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7),
    secondDieValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);

firstDie.innerHTML = firstDieValue;
secondDie.innerHTML = secondDieValue;

if (firstDieValue > secondDieValue) { ... }
```

Also, consider extracting your dice rolling strategy e.g.:

```
var diceRoll = randomDiceRoll(2),
    firstDieValue = diceRoll[0],
    secondDieValue = diceRoll[1];

function randomDiceRoll(diceCount) { 
    return Array.apply(0, Array(diceCount)).map(function () { 
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 7); 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are not parsing to integer the content of div value :

```
        var a  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        firstDie.innerHTML = a;
        secondDie.innerHTML = b;

        if (a>b)
        {
            document.getElementById("dice1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnspfg7p/5/

Comment: This'll work but it's rather convoluted to first generate random integers, then assign them to innerHTML, then retrieve the numbers back from the DOM, then parse the strings to convert them back to integers and finally compare them.